# $watch on complex expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an isolated scope variable in my direct that is an expression comprised the result of several other variables evaluated together such as:

```
<my-directive is-my-expr="!var1 && var2"></my-directive>
```

Where the directive is defined something similar to:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
           isMyExpr: '='
        },
        template: '<span>{{ isMyExpr ? "True" : "False" }}</span>',
        link: link
    };

    function link($scope) {
        $scope.$watch('isMyExpr', function (newValue) { $scope.isMyExpr = newValue; });
    }
});
```

However changing the values of var1 or var2 does not yield a change the displayed results of the directive. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you have a syntax error, it should be `'<span>{{ isMyExpr ? "True" : "False" }}</span>'` with quotes

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, this is not the verbatim code from my source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, you don't need to set up a `$watch` to manually update `$scope.isMyExpr` inside the directive. In fact, your watch as shown is redundant, because the listener function will only be called on initialisation and whenever the value changes.

What I recommend is to change to using an ampersand (`&`) binding for your isolate scope property. This will give you a `$scope.isMyExpr()` function on your scope that will evaluate to the result of the expression specified in the markup.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.var1 = $scope.var2 = false;
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      isMyExpr: '&'
    },
    template: "<span>{{ isMyExpr() ? 'True' : 'False' }}</span>",
    link: link
  };

  function link($scope) {
    /* nothing for now */
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="var1">Var1 = {{var1}}</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="var2">Var2 = {{var2}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      Inside my directive, isMyExpr() equals:
      <my-directive is-my-expr="!var1 && var2"></my-directive>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is [a working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iPlvpL?p=preview) of the same code.

Comment: Why the need for a function? It works just the same with `"="` http://plnkr.co/edit/tfwIbj4kJ6wAo9ZvIjdp?p=preview

Comment: Because "=" sets up a two way bound property. Since you don't need to update the parent scope by updating the isolate scope property (it is read-only), using the expression binding ("&") is more appropriate, I find. Plus it avoids setting up a watch on the isolate scope property, which means 1 less watch to process every digest.